# Force "save link as" with HTML, Javascript or ASP classic

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, asp-classic, download

I need to stop browsers opening PDFs in the browser. I would like to force download like the "save link as" option.

Currently using HTML5 element. Works in Chrome but not IE or  Firefox. My IIS doesnt seem to allow me to change the headers.

Would like a Javascript solution as I assume there isnt HTML or ASP classic option.

Sample code.

```
<a href="<%=link%>" target="_blank" download="<%=link%>"></a>
```

Comment: You can change the headers in IIS. See e.g. http://forums.iis.net/t/1190624.aspx/1

Comment: The guy in charge of the IIS says it cant. So far header solutions havent work so.

Comment: I don't think this is possible then. (The `download` property was introduced to do exactly this)

Comment: You could stop forcing your users to read a PDF the way you want them to. If I have PDFs set up to read in the browser, that's how I want to read them. If you don't want it read in the browser, don't serve it as a PDF. Zip it.

Comment: Dude not helpful. I am just doing what I am told to do.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, sorry. I work for people like that sometimes, too.

Answer (score -1):

Well what you can do is add a JS function to `onclick` event which alerts the users "Right click and click save as etc..." and then `return false;` so the `href` will not work.

Just in case for others you can force the download the file with adding some header to content. Sorry have no idea for classic ASP but it is like below for ASP.Net C# and I am prety sure you can find the same code for ASP.

```
        Response.ContentType = GetContentType(fileInfo.Extension);

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileInfo.Name + "\"");
        Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
        Response.End();
```

Last thing looks like this is working for the guys...
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/scripting/thread/045f4aa3-cab4-46fc-b9fe-891df3903244

Do not forget to add his last code as a solution.

Comment: an alert? are you serious?

Comment: why the -1? please explain.

Comment: well there is no other way to do that with a js/html. as he cannot change the header. Can use a dynamic page to return the pdf and change the header in that page but he is not looking for it.

Comment: Right, the solution is working but not a good practice in my opinion, that's why I downvoted. Removed.